# Stack in Virtualbox Manager | Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.2 amd64

Tags: virtualbox

I was configuring my Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS in Virtualbox before running it.
But there was a problem like which I posted.
What should I do next,
I have tried to disappear and appear the checklist many times to ensure that I could run the Ubuntu.
But still in a mess.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSQno.png)

Comment: Are you sure the only problem is on that tab? Try clicking the error at the bottom to see if you can get more details.

Comment: Yes only that thing, I also captured the problem and the error detail information. There, below of the picture I inserted was the information. Was that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If someone has a trouble to disable or enable 'hardware virtualization'.
You can check this website.[enter link description here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-hardware-virtualization-in-windows-10)
But, the references only for Windows 10 hosts.
Hope you fix the problem.